# Prime factors of a number in the form $2^n+1$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, prime-factorization, coprime

What is the gcd of $2^{55} +1$ and $165$?

This question was asked in KVPY 2019 SA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$165=5\times3\times11$

$2^{55}\equiv2^3\equiv3\pmod5$

$2^{55}\equiv2\equiv-1\pmod3$

$2^{55}\equiv2^5\equiv-1\pmod{11}$

Comment: I used Fermat's little theorem to get those congruences

Comment: So they're coprime

Comment: No, $3$ and $11$ but not $5$ divide $2^{55}+1$